# Waiting on thread until the callback success is received

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

I am calling a method that retrieves a list of places from google API.

```
nearByPlacesArray = gmObj.getNearbyPlaces(nameValuePairs);
    if (nearByPlacesArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nearByPlacesArray.length; i++) {
                nearbyPlaces.add(new mNearbyPlace(Integer.parseInt(nearByPlacesArray[i][0]), nearByPlacesArray[i][1], Double.parseDouble(nearByPlacesArray[i][2]), Double.parseDouble(nearByPlacesArray[i][3])));
            }
        }
```

And then build a list form it and pass it to a spinner adapter.

The function `getNearbyPlaces` runs asynchronously and uses Retrofit `success` callback to build a list of places and parse it.

The issue it when I call this function it returns a null object and move to next line of creating the list when the `nearByPlacesArray` is null.

I want to somehow stop processing further until the `success` method is called so the returned `nearByPlacesArray` is not null.

How can I do that?

```
public String[][] getNearbyPlaces(List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

        try {
            …
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(finalUri.toString()).build();
            IGooglePlacesApi iGPlaceApi = restAdapter.create(IGooglePlacesApi.class);

            iGPlaceApi.getStreams(new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    String serverResponse = retrofitError.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj, Response arg1) {
                    nearbyPlaces = new String[googlePlacesObj.results.size()][4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
                        mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
                        nearbyPlaces[i][0] = place.icon;
                        ...
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        …
        finally {
            Log.d("serverResponse:", serverResponse);
        }

        return nearbyPlaces;
    }
```

P.S. I am already doing all this on a different `async` thread not on main UI thread, so halting the flow won’t be a problem I guess.

Comment: You can add the result to a BlockingQueue and have your thread take()  an element.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting something in response of nearByPlacesArray. Thats why  it is going inside if block, so it happens when you get error msg/response from server. Because it treats error response as a something that is not null though it does have wrong info.

To handle this, you need to implement some validation functionality inside your "Callback" interface. that will solve the issue.